# Function which have to repeat in every wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

Hy, I want to make small slider in all of my wordpress posts which are on the same page so I need to repeat function in each post. Now if I put [working function](http://jsfiddle.net/4C5mK/2/)  in a loop  of post it's working only in a first one.I am new at coding so sorry if request looks a bit strange. Thx in advance.

```
<div class="butonas1">
   <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 100px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', 3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
<div id="MyDiv" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden">
   <div class="testas">djkgfjsdgfdskfg kkdsghf sdgkkgh ksdg kdsgk kjdshkshdgk hsd saflshf lsjfl lsjf lksjaflkjsalj fsafl sa a flkjsalfjslafl </div>
</div>

<div class="butonas1">
   <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 100px" onmousedown="scrollDiv('MyDiv', -3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
var timer1;
function scrollDiv(divId, depl) {
  var scroll_container = document.getElementById(divId);
  scroll_container.scrollLeft -= depl;
  timer1 = setTimeout('scrollDiv("'+divId+'", '+depl+')', 10);
}
</script>

<style>
.butonas1 {
float:left;
 width: 30px;
}
.testas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;    
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the ID of the div is static, it never changes, you must change the ID of the div

Inside the loop, do this:

in the loop do this:

```php
<?php $div = "MyDiv_" . get_the_ID(); ?>

<div class="butonas1">
    <input type="button" value="«" style="height: 100px" onmousedown="scrollDiv( '<?php echo $div; ?>', 3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
<div id="<?php echo $div; ?>" style="float: left; width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid; overflow: hidden">
    <div class="testas">djkgfjsdgfdskfg kkdsghf sdgkkgh ksdg kdsgk kjdshkshdgk hsd saflshf lsjfl lsjf lksjaflkjsalj fsafl sa a flkjsalfjslafl </div>
</div>

<div class="butonas1">
    <input type="button" value="»" style="height: 100px" onmousedown="scrollDiv( '<?php echo $div; ?>', -3)" onmouseup="clearTimeout(timer1)" />
</div>
```